# JavaFX image not changing when function is called by Platform.runLater

Tags: image, javafx

I have a function to change an image and its opacity in a JavaFX GUI:

```
private static Image image = null;
private static ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
   
// some code to add image in GUI

public static void changeImage() {
    imageView.setOpacity(0.5);
    imageView.setImage(null);
}
```

When I call this function within the JavaFX instance, the image disappears or is changing if I use an image instead of `null` for setImage(). I tried calling the function by pressing a button.

In this case all works as I expected.

When I call this function from another class, the actual image will change its opacity, but the image itself is never changing. I call the function the following way:

```
public static void changeImg() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> FX_Gui.changeImage());
}
```

Changing labels, progess bars... all works, but I did not manage to change an image.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In the code you have here, the opacity shouldn't even be apparent, as the image is Null.  It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: don't use static scope..

Comment: The code makes no sense, and the fact that everything is `static` is a huge code smell. Please create a [mre] and explain precisely what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: You say it’s called from another class.  More precisely, is this a case of a non-JavaFX event calling `runLater(() -> changeImg())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of aspects to this question that don't make sense.

Generally speaking, the GUI in JavaFX is intended to be self-contained and non-linear in it's execution.  Programming an outside method to **assume** some state of the GUI, and then to directly manipulate the GUI based on that assumption is not the correct approach.  So any attempt to *know* the state of the GUI by kludging in a `Thread.sleep()` call is inherently incorrect.

The `new JFXPanel()` call is not needed, as `Application.launch()` will initialize JavaFX.  Presumably, this was added before the `sleep(500)` was put in, since calling `changeImg()` would fail if run immediately after the `Thread.start()` command, since the `launch()` wouldn't have time to even start yet.

As has been noted, having some kind of startup image that's replaced once the screen completes initialization should be done from within the `FX_Min.start(Stage)` method, although it's highly unlikely that you'd even see the first image.

The question seems to be aimed at designing a kind of application where the GUI is just some small part of it and the main application is going to go on to do lengthy processing and then trigger the GUI to something in response to the results of that processing.  Or perhaps the main application is monitoring an external API and feeding updates to GUI periodically.  In most cases, however, the GUI is usually initialized so that it can take control of the operation, launching background threads to do the lengthy processing and using JavaFX tools to handle the triggering of GUI updates and intake of results.

In the instance that the design really needs to have something other than the GUI be the central control, then use of `Application` does not seem appropriate.  It is, after all, designed to control the **Application**, and monitors the status of the GUI once it's been launched to shut everything down when the GUI is closed.  This is why the OP had to put the `Application.launch()` call in a separate thread - `launch()` doesn't return until the GUI shuts down.

If the application outside of the GUI is going to control everything then it's best to manually start JavaFX with `Platform.startup()`, and handle all the monitoring manually.  The following code doesn't do any monitoring, but it does start up the GUI and change the image without any issues:

```
public class Control_Min {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Platform.startup(() -> new Fx_Min().start(new Stage()));
        Platform.runLater(() -> Fx_Min.changeImage());
    }
}
```

Note that no changes are required to the OP's code in `Fx_Min`. However, there's no reason for `Fx_Min` to extend `Application` any more, and the code from its `start()` method can be placed anywhere.

It should be further noted that, although this works, it's really way outside the norm for JavaFX applications.  It's possible that the OP's situation really does require this kind of architecture, but that would place it into a very small minority of applications.  Designing the application around `Application.launch()` and initiating lengthy processing in background threads through the JavaFX tools provided is almost always a better approach.

---

OK, so given new information from the OP it's clear that this should be based on `Application` and that the GUI should launch some kind of socket listener that would presumably block waiting for input.

Anything that blocks can't run on the FXAT, and there needs to be a way to allow the socket listener to communicate back to the GUI when it receives data.  Ideally, the socket listener should be JavaFX unaware, and just plain Java.

IMO, the best way to do this is to provide a `Consumer` to accept information from the socket listener, and to pass it to the socket listener in it's constructor.  That way, the GUI knows nothing about the nature of the socket listener except that it has a dependency on requiring a message consumer.  Similarly, the socket listener has no knowledge about what invoked it, just that it has given it a message consumer.

This limits your coupling, and you are free to write your GUI without worrying about any of the inner workings of the socket listener, and visa versa.

So here's the GUI, cleaned up and simplified a bit so that the socket listener stuff is easier to follow.  Basically, the GUI is just going to throw the message from the socket listener into a `Text` already on the screen.  The message consumer handles the `Platform.runLater()` so that the socket listener isn't even aware of it:

```
public class Fx_Min extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/images/ArrowUp.png"));
        Text text = new Text("");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(10, imageView, text), 800, 600));
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
        imageView.setImage(new Image("/images/Flag.png"));
        new SocketListener(socketMessage -> Platform.runLater(() -> text.setText(socketMessage))).startListening();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's the socket listener.  Clearly, this isn't going to listen on a socket, but it loops around a `sleep()` to simulate action happening on the Pi.  The message format here is `String`, just to keep everything simple, but obviously this is the worse possible choice for an actual implementation of this.  Build a special message class:

```
public class SocketListener {

    private Consumer<String> messageConsumer;

    public SocketListener(Consumer<String> messageConsumer) {
        this.messageConsumer = messageConsumer;
    }

    public void startListening() {
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(() -> listenForIRCommand());
        listenerThread.setDaemon(true);
        listenerThread.start();
    }

    private void listenForIRCommand() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                messageConsumer.accept("Station " + x);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be really clear that since the call to `listenForIRCommand()` is executed from inside a background thread, that it's completely freed from any JavaFX contstraints.  Anything that generally possible in Java can be done from there without worrying about it's impact on the GUI.

Comment: @kleopatra How did I not?

Comment: underscore in class names - even though that's taken from the question, it's not a good idea to propagate such violations, IMO :)

Answer (score -1):

In the meantime I found out that the reason for not changing the image is that I run changeImage() before the initialization of the GUI is completed. If I wait about 500 mS before I sent the changeImage() command all works fine.

Below is the minimal code that demonstrates the issue I had:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;

public class Control_Min {

    public static void changeImg() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> Fx_Min.changeImage());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Application.launch(Fx_Min.class);
            }
        }.start();
        // JFXPanel will initialize the JavaFX toolkit. 
        new JFXPanel();  
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        changeImg();        
    }
}
```

And the Gui itself:

```
public class Fx_Min extends Application {
    private static Stage stage;
    private static GridPane rootPane;
    private static Scene scene;
    private static Image image = null;  
    private static ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        stage = primaryStage;
        rootPane = new GridPane();
        scene = new Scene(rootPane,800,600);            
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Peter\\eclipse-workspace\\FX_Test\\src\\application\\Image1.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImage(image);
        rootPane.add(imageView, 1, 0);  
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.show();   
        System.out.println("Gui is ready");
    }
    
    public static void changeImage() {
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Peter\\eclipse-workspace\\FX_Test\\src\\application\\Image2.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImage(image);
        System.out.println("Image Changed");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This code works fine.
In the console I get:
Gui is ready
Image Changed

When I remove the Thread.sleep(500) the image will not change.
In the console I get:
Image Change
Gui is ready
My conclusion is that I have send the runlater method before the FX runtime has been initialized.
(Have not fixed the static issue yet as this was not the issue. I will do in my original program later.)

My task is the following:
I program a GUI for my internet radio player on my PC.
The GUI controls the radio and polls what is playing.
I want to control the radio by an IR remote control too.
I have already a Raspberry Pi that communicates with the remote.
Therefore, my plan is to run a server socket on the PC, that receives the commands from the Raspberry Pi.
The server will run in its own thread. I want to use the runLater command to update the GUI.
Is there a better way to update the GUI from the server?
Goal is that the GUI will update immediately when I press a button on the remote.
With my latest learnings about JavaFX I will start the application now directly in the FX class and get the server thread started from the FX class

Comment: You should really provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. Your solution is surprising based on the small snippets of code you've already given.

Comment: ... and why that weird setup (launching the application from a different class vs. from itself) ? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: In this case, your solution looks like an attempt to fix the wrong problem. What are you really trying to accomplish with the convoluted code in `Control_Min#main(String[])`? Why is that where you call the change-image method instead of from `FX_Min#start(Stage)`?